# Upgraded Python does not Recognize Modules (Mac)

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, package, upgrade

I recently upgraded from Python 3.8.5 to Python 3.11.2. I updated my pip and pip3 to use the correct directory. However, when I run my previously existing code from Jupyter notebook, I get: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". I tried uninstalling and installing requests, updating Jupiter notebook, and installing requests again using brew and nothing worked. The same goes for the Ta-lib library. Was wondering what I was doing wrong thanks.

Comment: You might need to recreate the virtual environment for the new Python install.

Comment: You didn't "upgrade" Python, you installed an entirely new interpreter. You have to install the modules again. You should be using virtual environments anyway. You are almost certainly installing things for the original interpreter

Comment: If you ran `pip install requests` and you are still getting the ModuleNotFoundError, then I suspect you did _not_, in fact, "update my pip and pip3 to use the correct directory".  How, exactly, did you do that update?

Comment: @JohnGordon I used "ln -s -f $(which pip3.11) $(which pip3)" and then the same for "python" which then allowed for "python --version" to display the new version but evidently did not do entirely what I wanted from it.

Comment: I think you got your `ln` arguments backwards.  That command rewrote `pip3.11` to be the same command as `pip3`, but you wanted the opposite...

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh my bad, so do I just need to flip it?

Comment: I think it would have worked the first time with flipped arguments.  But not anymore, because pip3.11 has already been overwritten.

Comment: @JohnGordon makes sense. So best to uninstall and start again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I removed and reinstalled both versions 3.8.5 and 3.11 of Python. I then used a virtual environment to access my work depending on which version of Python is necessary and everything is working.